# WebGL ThreeJS and PhysiJS in angularJS unable to launch physics?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js, webgl, physics-engine

OK here goes I'm running some Webgl experiments using ThreeJS and PhysiJS wrapping them in angularJS.
and I can't get the gravity to kick in,you can find an example of my problem here:

http://buildawebdoctor.com/canvas/#/spiro_eight

I'm getting a plethora of errores in the console:

```
gl.getProgramInfoLog() warning: Variable sampler array index unsupported.
This feature of the language was removed in GLSL 1.20 and is unlikely to be supported     for 1.10 in Mesa.
```

<strike>this error is a bug on my GPU i think:</strike>
it's a warning not a error
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4507

then two undefined is not a function, calls.
the file with the Physics in it is this one:

https://github.com/vimes1984/spiro/blob/master/scripts/controllers/spiro_eight.js

I don't have enough knowledge about webworkers to fix it..
could someone point me in the right direction or at least give me a explanation on why it's not working...

Answer (score 1):

ok if anybody comes up with this problem again it's because the build of ammo.js didn't inluce the btHeightfieldTerrainShape wasn't included in the ammo.js build. 
There is a new version here for all that need it: 
https://github.com/vimes1984/spiro/blob/master/bower_components/ammo.js/builds/ammo.js

Answer (score 0):

They are already wrapped into simple API in project named [WhitestormJS](https://github.com/WhitestormJS/whitestorm.js) you can try using it. Here is a [docs website](https://whitestormjs.xyz/). + Physics in whitestorm.js is a little bit improved cause [Physi.js is old today and uses Ammo.js version that was built 4 years ago](https://medium.com/whitestormjs-framework/porting-bullet-physics-into-ammo-js-and-improving-physi-js-f0130c372f91#.jmk25r52g).

P.s.: In the newest version it has also softbody feature.
I hope it will be useful for you!

**And some examples for you:**

- [FPS / Shooter](http://192.241.128.187/current/examples/fps/shooter/)  (First person example with Wagner effects and terrain. + fog)
- [Physics / Dominos](http://192.241.128.187/current/examples/physics/domino/)  (Physics example with dominos.)
- [Performance / Sticks](http://192.241.128.187/current/examples/performance/sticks/)  (Collisions performance of 320 basic box objects.)
- [Basic / Softbody](http://192.241.128.187/current/examples/basic/softbody/)  (Basic softbody implementation.)